# Where can I buy photographic film in Prague, CZ?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, film

I'm currently in Prague and, like every self respecting film photographer out there, I forgot to pack my rolls of film.

Is there anywhere I can purchase BW film (135 and 120) in Prague? I'm looking for a place with a good selection of brands, if any. I'm not really a fan on the leftover half-expired Kodaks one can often find in "professional photographer" stores.

Comment: I'm sure someone will be along very quickly to say that this site really isnt for this sort of question...
Also, you have the internet in-front of you; http://www.fotoskoda.cz/filmy/

I love that its called "Filmy"!!

Comment: @DigitalLightcraft "y" is the masculine inanimate plural suffix, so a lot of foreign words end up written that way. I agree it's kind of funny as a native English speaker — it makes everything seem cute.

Comment: You have just re-discovered one of the many advantages of digital versus film.  Maybe it's time to move on.

Comment: @OlinLathrop In no way is that a reason to move on. Actually I don't even think that `moving on` is the right expression to be used here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went to [Foto Skoda](http://www.fotoskoda.cz) as suggested in the comments and found what I was looking for. It's worthy to note that the in-store selection is substantially more limited with respect to the online catalogue, as one would expect. Nevertheless the shop is well equipped to cater for basic needs, such as the ones I had, and the prices are acceptable.